# Make an adaptive iframe, then allow fullscreen upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am using this code for getting an adaptive iframe which has fixed ratio width and height:

```
<div id="game-container" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; padding-top: 60%">
<iframe  style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="example.html">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Then, I have created a button with class "toggle_fullscreen" and insert this JS to allow fullscreen upon clicking the button:

```
var game = $("#game-container");
var FSbutton = $(".toggle_fullscreen");
var gm = game[0];
FSbutton.on('click', function(e){
if (gm.requestFullscreen) {
  gm.requestFullscreen();
} else if (gm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  gm.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (gm.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  gm.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}});
```

This works well when the width of the iframed element is larger than the height, but if not, what happens is that the width becomes 100% and the element is not shown in full. I tried to play a bit more with the code, but didn't figure it out. Can you suggest a better way to have an adaptive iframe (with a maximum width) which can be made fullscreen upon request?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this question: [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css).
Use it in your `example.html` to make your content with fixed ratio.

Comment: Thank you. I already have achieved this part. The issue is when I make the iframe go fullscreen. If the height is larger than the width, things go wrong.